# Query using "contains" check in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table in dynamo which has following fields:

1. **a_id**
2. **b_id**
3. **id**
4. **name**
5. **name_UC** (same as 4 but in capital letters)

**1 and 2** are the `Partition key` and **3** as the `Sort key`.
There's one Local Secondary Index (LSI) having **1 and 2** as the `Partition key` and **5** as `Sort key`.

---

Initially, I used to fetch all the fields where name began with a certain substring. I did this by using LSI. I got a different use case where I needed to fetch all the fields containing a certain substring. Now,

1. Amazon doesn't allow users to use contains on an indexed column. Hence, I can't query dynamodb from my service on LSI here.
2. After removing the index and querying on the main table using contains following error occurred:

> ***Error Description*** - *The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning
>   level with the UpdateTable API.
>
>   (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status
>   Code: 400; 
> Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException;)*

Is there any way to solve this problem without increasing the provisioned throughput capacity?